# Lebesgue Measure on $1$-dimensional Euclidean Space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$,
with $m(E) < \infty$,
then there exists a compact subset $K$ of $E$, s.t.
$m(K)=\frac{1}{2}m(E)$.

My attempt:
$\forall x \geq 0$, define a function
$$f(x)=m(E \cap [-x,x]) \; .$$
For any $0 \leq x < y$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2|y-x| \; ,$$
hence $f$
is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, since
$$
f(0)=0 \;, f(\infty)=m(E) \; ,
$$
then by Intermidiate Value Thm., there
exists $x_0 \in (0,\infty)$, s.t.
$$m(E \cap [-x_0,x_0])=f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}m(E) \; .$$
Since $E \cap [-x_0,x_0]$ is measurable,
then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists compact subset
$K_n$ of $E \cap [-x_0,x_0]$, s.t.
$$m((E \cap [-x_0,x_0])\setminus K_n) < \frac{1}{n} \; .$$
But we could not say $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}K_n$ is compact.
Then I got stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is obvious of $m(E)=0$ so assume $0 <m(E) <\infty$. There exists a compact set $K_0 \subseteq E$ such that $\frac 1 2 m(E) <m(K_0) <m(E)$. Apply your argument with $E$ replaced by $K_0$. You will get $x_0$ such that $m([-x_0,x_0]\cap K_0)=
\frac 1  2 m(E)$.  Take $K=[-x_0,x_0]\cap K_0$.